# Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Why do I get error 「Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.」

・Error procedure

1.Input form data

2.Click submit(dispatch "setFormData")

3.Input form data

4.error

When input form data，I set data into tmpFormData.
tmpFormData is not vuex state.
It is components data.

Maybe，when exec 「this.$store.dispatch('ranks/setFormData', this.tmpFormData)」

Is tmpFormData and formData connected?

pages/search.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-form ref="form" v-on:submit.prevent="search">
      <v-list width=100%>
        <v-list-item v-for="(criteria, name, i) in searchCriterias" :key="i">
          <v-subheader>{{criteria.name}}</v-subheader>
            <template v-if="criteria.type=='checkbox'">
              <v-checkbox
                v-for="(item, j) in criteria.items" :key="j"
                v-model="tmpFormData[name]"
                :label="item"
                :value="j + 1"
              ></v-checkbox>
            </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    <v-btn color="success" class="mr-4" type="submit">Search</v-btn>
  </v-form>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        tmpFormData: {
          search_1: null,
          search_2: null,
          search_3: null,
          search_4: null,
        },
        searchCriterias: {
          search_1: {
            name: "sex",
            items: ["male", "female"],
          },
        search_2: {
            name: "price",
            items: [
              {label: "not selected", value: 0},
              {label: "under 8000yen", value: 1}
            ],
        },
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async search() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('ranks/setFormData', this.tmpFormData)
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

store/search.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  formData: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  setFormData(state, formData) {
    state.formData = formData
  },
}

export const actions = {
  async setFormData({ commit, getters }, formData) {
    commit('setFormData', formData)
  },
}

export const getters = {
  formData (state) {
    return state.formData
  },
}
```

The error disappeared when I fixed it as follows, but I don't know why

```
setFormData(state, formData) {
  state.formData.search_1 = formData.search_1
  state.formData.search_2 = formData.search_2
  state.formData.search_3 = formData.search_3
  state.formData.search_4 = formData.search_4
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have set `strict: true` on vuex.

In this mode, vuex warns you, when you manipulate any state without using a mutation. With this statement `v-model="tmpFormData[name]"` you do exactly that.

You can either disable strict mode or use something like `vuex-map-fields`

Comment: Thank you! It was solved if I followed your advice!